# Accessing UIPopoverController from UIActionSheet

Tags: ios, ipad, uipopovercontroller, uiactionsheet

I have `UIActionSheet` presented from `UIPopopverController`. How to get `UIPopoverController` from `UIActionSheet` delegate `-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex`?

Answer (score 0):

There's no build/in way to do that.

You may consider adding a `popoverController` property on the delegate and setting it before presenting the popover.

Comment: But how would the popoverController actually reference the popover associated with the action sheet?